# Iterating through regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, iteration

I have a basic knowledge of python (completed one class) and I'm unsure of how to tackle this next script.  I have two files, one is a newick tree - looks like this, but much larger:

```
(((1:0.01671793,2:0.01627631):0.00455274,(3:0.02781576,4:0.05606947):0.02619237):0.08529440,5:0.16755623);
```

The second file is a tab delimited text file that looks like this but is much larger:

```
1 \t Human
2 \t Chimp
3 \t Mouse
4 \t Rat
5 \t Fish
```

I want to replace the sequence ID numbers (only those followed by colons) in the newick file with the species names in the text file to create

```
(((Human:0.01671793,Chimp:0.01627631):0.00455274,(Mouse:0.02781576,Rat:0.05606947):0.02619237):0.08529440,Fish:0.16755623);
```

My pseudocode (after opening both files) would look something like

```
for line in txtfile:
    if line[0] matches \(\d*\ in newick:
        replace that \d* with line[2]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done by defining a callback function that is run on every match of the regexp `\(\d*:`.

here's an (unrelated) example from https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#text-munging that illustrates how the callback function is used together with `re.sub()` that performs the regexp substitution:

```
>>> def repl(m):
...   inner_word = list(m.group(2))
...   random.shuffle(inner_word)
...   return m.group(1) + "".join(inner_word) + m.group(3)
>>> text = "Professor Abdolmalek, please report your absences promptly."
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)(\w+)(\w)", repl, text)
'Poefsrosr Aealmlobdk, pslaee reorpt your abnseces plmrptoy.'
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)(\w+)(\w)", repl, text)
'Pofsroser Aodlambelk, plasee reoprt yuor asnebces potlmrpy.'
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question exactly?

Comment: this is the proposed solution, what's unclear about it? here's how it works: http://codepad.org/gGcb5mdq

Comment: Your codepad makes sense and passing a callable to `re.sub` is the way to go... what I don't understand is how demonstrating it via text munging is useful. You might just as well have said *this can be done by defining a callback function that is run on every match of the regexp* and leave it at that...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `findall`:

```
import re

s = "(((1:0.01671793,2:0.01627631):0.00455274,(3:0.02781576,4:0.05606947):0.02619237):0.08529440,5:0.16755623)"

rep = {'1':'Human',
'2':'Chimp',
'3':'Mouse',
'4':'Rat',
'5':'Fish'}

for i in re.findall(r'(\d+:)', s):
    s = s.replace(i, rep[i[:-1]]+':')

>>> print s
(((Human:0.01671793,Chimp:0.01627631):0.00455274,(Mouse:0.02781576,Rat:0.05606947):0.02619237):0.08529440,Fish:0.16755623)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  unfortunately, as soon as you have a list of more than 9 species, it gets rather messy.  The solution above worked like a charm though!